# SQL Trigger then display result

Tags: sql, triggers

First time poster, I apologize for my ignorance:

My scenario is: When a column gets updated in a table (we will call this STATUS), I need to get the result of the value of column CLOSING (in the same table and row) and transmit this value (and only this value of this column).

```
CREATE TRIGGER Z_Trigger 
   AFTER UPDATE of Status
    On Batch
```

Status being my column name
Batch being my table name.

How do I acquire the value for the other column CLOSING and then have that value displayed or even exportable?
[By exportable, I mean I will then want that value emailed automatically, (but that's a whole other part).  I'm trying to focus on this one at a time.]

Something like, AFTER UPDATE OF STATUS ON BATCH [then display column CLOSING] onto screen for user to see.

Comment: You cannot use a trigger to display data.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... Triggers on the other hand are **highly vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....